# WCF Get data when maxreceivedmessagesize error

Tags: c#, wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

I have a maxreceivedmessagesize error in my application.

When this error happend, I would show a Message to the user, and I want to display the data that have been loaded before exceeding the maximum size.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 options here :

- Rewrite the entire soap framework to pass the partial data back(not recommended)
- Increase the data size so the soap framework will pass the message back. Then check the size and show an appropriate message.

You can increase the size in your web.config on your binding. You should set maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize to the same value.